# How should I position two shelf supports for the minimum deflection?

Tags: structures

[image: A shelf]

The above is the shelf that I'm intending to put up.  It will have two symmetrically placed supports. This is probably a simple question that really should be answered in all DIY shops but...

Assuming a uniformly distributed load across the entire shelf, what should the value of **x** be to obtain the minimum deflection anywhere along L?

Comment: @Wasabi Ah.  So x = 0.6ish?

Comment: @PaulUszak It depends on how you intend to build and load the shelf.  There are multiple ways to attach the supports and depending on the specifics of your situation some may be better than others for specific loads.

Comment: @Paul Uszak: not an answer, but if you could find a formula online for max deflection, as a function of span length and overhang length, you could find the minimum with some simple math (i.e. derivative of deflection for span length variable is equal to zero)